Command locations in Ubuntu
For example, when I run the clear command in the Ubuntu Terminal, how does Ubuntu know whether it should run /usr/bin/clear or /bin/clear? Is there an alias for this job somewhere in Ubuntu?
I ran which -a clear to list clear's locations.
The output is:
/usr/bin/clear
/bin/clear

Then I looked at my ~/.bashrc file, but I couldn't find any alias for command locations.

/bin is a symlink to /usr/bin, so the entire directory (including all executables) are mirrored in both directories. Please see above for explanation on symlinks.

I don't think this question has been closed for the "right" duplicate(s). I think OP is concerned about why /usr/bin/clear is picked over /bin/clear, not why about the same executable is run, which makes the links to the symlink stuff not relevant.

Understanding how PATH environment variable works is kinda relevant but quotes a snippet of man bash which doesn't address how executables are selected when parsing PATH. Adding to this, I couldn't find a Q/A explicitly addressing this (I could find just this one on U&L). So I voted to reopen this. If OP, @ArturMeinild or muru disagree with my reasoning please ping me, maybe I'm missing something.

@kos "... bash searches  each  element  of the PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that name.  Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files [...].   A  full  search  of  the directories in PATH is performed only if the command  is  not  found  in  the  hash  table." seems reasonably clear to me - Pick whichever is first in PATH.

I think this is just OP labouring under a misconception that commands have to have aliases if you're executing it without specifying the full path. I think that's cleared up in the thorough explanation in the quoted part of the manpage.

@muru It's reasonable to infer that "the first exectuable found will be run", my problem is just that it's not explicitly mentioned, and that in general that Q/A addresses dfferent aspects of PATH. Since we don't have a "canonical" "how does PATH work?" kind of Q/A, all things considered, maybe this should be reopened and it could become that missing Q/A? I mean, unless I missed the duplicate of course, as I often do. I just find it a bit of stretch to link this to a mostly unrelated question which doesn't really address the issue thoroughly (the issue mentioned here that is).

@muru "how does Ubuntu know whether it should run /usr/bin/clear or /bin/clear" - I read it as "how does it pick between the two" rather than "how does it know that it has to run either", but sure enough only OP could tell at this point

@kos "Understanding how PATH environment variable works" is a general enough title that you can make it the canonical "how does PATH work?" QA

@muru Yeah people do post answers to unrelated questions when the title is so misleading or general that most people that end up visiting the question are actually looking for someting else, however I can't get that question to show up at all googling or searching on the site (for example) stuff like "How does PATH work" / "How does PATH work Ubuntu", or similar. So I don't know how I feel about that. Granted, I'm not saying this Q would become the grand hub of people looking for an answer to this problem either. But at least answers would match the question.

@muru IDK, let's leave it to reopen voters to decide I guess... In the meantime I'll try and find a better duplicate
